# What happens to CompleteableFuture when it gets neither completed, cancelled nor an exception?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, garbage-collection, completable-future

... vs using a callback?

First example, with callback

```
public class NewClass {

    public static final ScheduledExecutorService SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface F_CallbackDef {

        void callback(String s);
    }

    public void a() {
        b((String s) -> {
            System.out.println(s);
        });
    }

    public void b(F_CallbackDef callback) {
        SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR.schedule(() -> {
            String s = "string";
            Random random = new Random();
            boolean cond = random.nextBoolean();
            if (cond) {
                boolean cond2 = random.nextBoolean();
                if (cond2) {
                   // assume possible uncatched exeption
                }
                callback.callback(s);
                // in every case:
                // callback just moves out of scope - no problem
            }
        }, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```

Second example, with CompletableFuture

```
public class NewClass1 {

    public static final ScheduledExecutorService SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void a() {
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = b();
        cf.thenAcceptAsync((String s) -> {
            System.out.println(s);
        });

        // cf moves out of scope immediatly
        // but also it gets never completed, nor cancelled
    }

    CompletableFuture<String> b() {
        CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
        SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR.schedule(() -> {
            String s = "string";
            Random random = new Random();
            boolean cond = random.nextBoolean();
            if (cond) {
                boolean cond2 = random.nextBoolean();
                if (cond2) {
                    // assume possible uncatched exception
                }
                result.complete(s);
            }

            // assume cond = false or cond2 = false
            // this is not about that result.cancel() SHOULD be called, it is a bug if you will
        }, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Question are:

- What happens to cf in example 2 / (When) Will it be removed by garbage collection?
- Is there any better way to "translate" example 1 into example 2?

In your answer, please kindly stay sharp to technical arguments and not to preferred/improvable code (because that is not what this question is about), nor is it about that cf.cancel does not get called.

Comment: Why don't you check the source to see how and when `CompletableFuture` get out of scope? That's the sharpest technical argument available. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java

Comment: @M.leRutte you mean like only the callback survives? And when its execution is finished, everything is collected? Please share your (the) answer.

Comment: Note that scope does not control garbage collection, reachability does. In both your examples, the `F_CallbackDef` and the `CompletableFuture` instances become unreachable after the code within the task submitted to the executor is executed. They'll be garbage collected at some later point. In the case of the CF, no completions will be triggered if `cond` was `false`.

Comment: What I meant is that the source of `CompletableFuture` is publicly available, thus open to inspection to see why chained futures remain reachable and when they become unreachable and thus eligible for garbage collection. Method scope has nothing to do with this. Looking at the source is "the truth" instead of speculation.

Comment: @M.leRutte have you actually dug into the `CompletableFuture` code? It is probably one of the most complex pieces of code I have seen, with 2000+ lines of code, 25 inner classes, complex lock handling etc. I don't think it would really help. One can provide a technical explanation without entering in such details.

Comment: @DidierL How? In general the mechanics for garbage collection and reachability are known, so you cannot discuss this without looking at the code before you know how it is implemented. Otherwise it is just  guessing how it probably works, and the OP didn't want that.

Comment: @M.leRutte You have to assume that `CompletableFuture`-related objects do not leak, and so no reference is kept after the execution of the tasks you submit, and their descendants. Based on this, you can simply reason on what references must be kept, and how long. Basically, that's the reasoning of Sotirios. Also note that, as I understand it, Martin indicated this in his question so that the answers do not drift towards a code review.

Comment: I consider the 'reasoning' to be guessing. But I agree with you, in general one can try to reason how you'd keep the object graph reachable until the chain becomes an island. And I have enough confidence in the Java team to assume that they've thought this well through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What happens to the `CompletableFuture`? When will it be removed by garbage collection?

In your code, you have 3 references to the `CompletableFuture`:

- the local variable `cf` in `a()`
- the local variable `result` in `b()`
- the captured reference in the lambda passed to `SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR.schedule()`

Also note that the lambda that is passed to `thenAcceptAsync()` needs to be kept at least as long as the completable future is uncompleted, except if the completable future itself is gc'd. So even if you don't keep a reference to it, this lambda might live longer than the execution of the method.

Nothing special applies concerning `CompletableFuture`s, standard GC rules apply: it will become eligible for garbage collection when nothing references it anymore – or more precisely when there exists no path to the GC roots anymore.

For local variables it's quite easy to see when they stop referencing it. For the captured reference, unfortunately it will remain as long as the lambda lives (even if it does not use it anymore). Assuming optimization, the lambda will be eligible for GC when no more executions are planned – so here it would be when you shutdown your executor.

Once those references are gone, it will thus be eligible for GC.

### Is there any better way to "translate" example 1 into example 2?

The *translation* is not actually correct because a `CompletableFuture` can be completed only once. In example 1, your callback will be called for each successful execution, but in example 2, only the first successful one will trigger it. The next calls to `result.complete(s)` will actually be ignored.

`CompletableFuture` is not designed to handle a flow of result values. For that you should go towards reactive programming with observables and subscribers.

If this was for a single execution, the conversion would be correct, however it would be better to just rely on `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` than handling the future yourself. This would also automatically provide exception handling features.

Answer (score -3):

In example 1, when you call `a` it calls `b` that schedules a task, and `a` returns. At some point the the callback will be executed by the thread that is running a task created inside `b`.

In example 2, when you call `a` it calls `b` that schedules a task and `a` returns. Code inside `thenAcceptAsync` is never executed, because you've never called that Future's `get`.  `cf` is a local variable, so the object it points to becomes available for GC after `a` terminates.  At some point GC may remove it.

If your were to call `get` somewhere in your code, it would block until the task would have completed, and then execute the clause in `thenAcceptAsync` in the context of the thread that is calling `get`.

There is no way to `translate` example 1 to example 2, because they are doing 2 quite different things, each of which may be correct depending on your requirements.

One other thing that you seem to be confused about: futures are neither completed nor cancelled, the tasks that they are pointing to ARE. They only provide the ability to get to the results of the task they are pointing to in the future.

Comment: I think you are "confused" about Future (an interface) and CompleteableFuture (implementing Future). Also it is my opinion you are underestimating the question. The fact that cf runs out of scope is the exact observation I am curious about, because the callback might still fire.

Comment: I mean the completeablefuture might still get completed :-)

Comment: 'Code inside thenAcceptAsync is never executed, because you've never called that Future's get' 
that is just wrong